# Como hago para poner contenido xaml en la pagina principal de una aplicación con menú MasterDetail?

Tags: xamarin

Tengo una app en Xamarin Forms con xaml y tengo el menu lateral de las 3 rayitas que se abre al hacerle click, como sabran tengo el archivo .xaml y .xaml.cs del menu y del detalle, pero quiero meter contenido por defecto es decir cuando se inicia la aplicacion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2.Push"
            x:Class="App2.Page1"
            Title="Menu">
   <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
       <Label Text="CardView Demo in Xamarin Forms"  
              FontAttributes="Bold"  
              FontSize="Medium"  
              VerticalOptions="Start"  
              HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  
              VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  
              BackgroundColor="Transparent"  
              HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
       <ListView x:Name="listView"   
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelcetedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"   
                 HasUnevenRows="True"  
                 ItemsSource="{Binding lstUsers}" >
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>
                       <local:CardViewTemplate/>
                   </ViewCell>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
   </StackLayout>
   
</MasterDetailPage>
```

el codigo de arriba me dice:

Error   XLS0504 La propiedad 'Detail' no admite valores de tipo 'StackLayout'

Alguna sugerencia?